# Как завести участок кода jQuery (if \ else)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular2, frontend

Здравствуйте. Есть такой участок кода:

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
jQuery('.speaker').text(jQuery('.speaker').data('text'));
jQuery('.speaker').click( function () {
        var speakerText = jQuery(this).closest(".row").text();

        if(jQuery(this).data('lang') == 'RU') {
            var speakerLang = 'Russian Female';
        } else {
            var speakerLang = 'Polish Female';
        }

        if(jQuery("#resume").hasClass("speaker_play")) {
            responsiveVoice.resume();
            jQuery(".speaker_play").removeAttr("id");

        } else {
        responsiveVoice.speak(speakerText, speakerLang,  {rate: jQuery(this).data('rate')});
    };
        jQuery('.speaker_play').hide();
        jQuery('.speaker').show();
        jQuery(this).hide();
        jQuery('.speaker_play').text(jQuery('.speaker_play').data('text'));
        jQuery(this).closest(".speaker__inner").children('.speaker_play').show();
});

jQuery('.speaker_play').click( function () {
    responsiveVoice.pause();
    jQuery(this).hide();
    jQuery(this).closest(".speaker__inner").children('.speaker').show();
    jQuery('.speaker_play').attr('id', 'resume');
});
});
```

Функция заключается в том, что бы по API отправить данные на аудио "говорилку", скрипт вполне себе рабочий без проверки в 13 строке

```
if(jQuery("#resume").hasClass("speaker_play"))
```

Но проверка мне нужна для того что бы не сбрасывать сброс спича, а возобновлять, если раннее был клик по кнопке Остановить (id="resume").

Дефолтная разметка (без клика)

```
<div class="speaker__inner"><input type="submit" class="speaker" data-lang="RU" data-rate="0.85" value="Озвучить текст"><input type="submit" class="speaker_play" value="Остановить текст"></div>
```

Помогите :)

Comment: А где ваша разметка? Может быть у вас блок с id равным `resume` не имеет класса `speaker_play`.

Comment: Сделал обновление поста